# Accessing data in a nested dict? Python

Tags: python, variables

I have the following data from a response. This appears to be a dict.

I'm able to access, for example, "description". Can you please advise on what I should be reading to allow me to access the "tcp_options" bit. I'm assuming this is a nested dict.

```
  {
  "description": "sftp",
  "icmp_options": null,
  "is_stateless": false,
  "protocol": "6",
  "source": "127.0.0.1/32",
  "source_type": "CIDR_BLOCK",
  "tcp_options": {
    "destination_port_range": null,
    "source_port_range": {
      "max": 5500,
      "min": 5500
    }
  },
  "udp_options": null
  },
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: You say that you can access `"description"`, so that means you can access `"tcp_options"`. Is there another problem you have not mentioned yet?

Comment: All, especiallit quamrana. Yes I guess i should have mentioned, when trying to access the "tcp_options" I get. KeyError: 'tcp_options'. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To access an element in a nested dict in python, like this:

```
thing = { "hi":{"hello":"bye"}}
```

You would write:

```
print(thing["hi"]["hello"])
```

This should return the following:

```
>>> print(thing["hi"]["hello"])
bye
>>> ...
```

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Nice thank you. I maybe should have added I get the following error: KeyError: 'tcp_options'

Comment: Also I tried to "thumbs up" your post, but it won't allow me.

Comment: Don't worry, its because those with >15 reputation can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

All,

Firstly thank you for your inputs. But it turns out I'm a bit of an idiot.

`'tcp_options"':`

Actually has an " in there and that's whay I was getting the error. I thought the " was some form of mystical python voodoo.

Sorry, but thank you all.

*edit* : my line of code: print(newRules['tcp_options"']['destination_port_range']['min']) now actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the `dict` by its key value should do just fine:

```
dd = {
  "description": "sftp",
  "icmp_options": 'null',
  "is_stateless": 'false',
  "protocol": "6",
  "source": "127.0.0.1/32",
  "source_type": "CIDR_BLOCK",
  "tcp_options": {
    "destination_port_range": 'null',
    "source_port_range": {
      "max": 5500,
      "min": 5500
    }
  },
  "udp_options": 'null'
  }

for key,value in dd.items():
    print(key,value)


print(dd["tcp_options"])
```

OUTPUT:

```
description sftp                                                                                                                                                             
source_type CIDR_BLOCK                                                                                                                                                       
protocol 6                                                                                                                                                                   
source 127.0.0.1/32                                                                                                                                                          
icmp_options null                                                                                                                                                            
tcp_options {'source_port_range': {'max': 5500, 'min': 5500}, 'destination_port_range': 'null'}                                                                              
is_stateless false                                                                                                                                                           
udp_options null                                                                                                                                                             
{'source_port_range': {'max': 5500, 'min': 5500}, 'destination_port_range': 'null'}
```